# Unable to connect to database using ODBC

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, odbc

I have a C# Windows Forms Application, .NET 4.5.2.

I'm trying to connect to a postgres database in localhost. What I do is define the following connection string:

```
connectionString = "Driver={PostgreSQL};Server=127.0.0.1;Port=5432;Database=Project;Uid=postgres;Pwd=password;"
```

And then, I try to make a query to database and get result in a DataTable using the following function:

```
//Makes a query to DB, returns result as DataTable
public DataTable MakeQuery(string query)
{
    //Create connection to DataBase
    ODBCConnection connection = new OdbcConnection(connectionString); 

    //Open connection
    connection.Open(); //HERE I GET ERROR

    //Create OdbcCommand using provided query
    OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand(query);

    //Assign connection to OdbcCommand
    command.Connection = connection;

    //DataTable with query result
    DataTable result = new DataTable();

    //Adapter to fill DataTable with query result
    OdbcDataAdapter adapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(command);

    //Make query and fill DataTable with result
    adapter.Fill(result);

    //Closing connection
    connection.Close();

    //Returning result
    return result;
} //MakeQuery
```

The error I get when trying to open connection:

```
"ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC controllers administrator] Data origin name not found and no default controller specified"
```

(Error message translated from spanish, so it may not be exactly that)

So it seems like connection string is not working, but I'm pretty sure it has the correct format. I copied it from this link: https://www.connectionstrings.com/postgresql-odbc-driver-psqlodbc/

I'm sure IP and Port is correct. I'm also sure I specified correctly database name, username and password. Is there some problem with PostgreSQL driver in .NET? Is there something wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by using {PostgreSQL UNICODE} driver, no idea why default won't work